# Triggering drag-drop events from within hammer JS press event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, hammer.js

I have a draggable div which has HTML 5 drag and drop listeners attached to it and the entire drag drop operation works fine on a desktop. Same functionality I am trying to achieve on touch devices such that on long press the selection becomes draggable and with touch movement on the device the drag-drop operation gets completed. I have tried the following approach using hammerJS but I am not able to achieve the functionality.

```
function enableTouch() {

    var divData = document.getElementById("testEvent1");
    var options ={preventDefault: true, domEvents: true};
    var hammertime = new Hammer(divData,options);

    hammertime.on('press', function(ev) {
        console.log("Div Pressed" + ev);
        $("#testEvent1").trigger("dragstart");
    });
}
```

The enableTouch function gets called only when its a touch enabled device.
Here I am getting "Div Pressed" on the console but I am not able to trigger the subsequent drag drop event listeners that are attached to my div.

PS: Hammer 2.0 doesn't have dragstart,drag defined any more. So I have to depend on "press" to trigger drag somehow.

I would appreciate any kind of suggestions. Thanks in advance.